# Generating a Random Salt and use it in Bcrypt

Tags: php, random, hash, bcrypt, salt

I am trying to generate a random salt to be used in hashing a password. 
I am a bit new to password hashing, but form what I understand, when using BCrypt algorithm, you will get as a result a 60 characters long hashed string.

22 characters Out of these 60 characters should the salt value, which is prepended to the resulting hash.

I used a simple code to make sure that the randomly generated salt is the same one that is going to be prepended to the actual hash:

```
$salt = substr(strtr(base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(22)), '+', '.'), 0, 22);
echo "Salt Value is: ".$salt . "\n";
```

The output was: **Salt Value is: XKFB8DHMiXaYTzRAHtRhX7**

Then I encrypted a password using the same generated salt as follows:

```
$cost = 8; 
$EncryptedPassword = password_hash($Password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => $cost,'salt' => $salt]);
echo "Encrypted Password: " . $EncryptedPassword . "\n";
```

The output was not what I expected:

**Encrypted format: $2y$10$XKFB8DHMiXaYTzRAHtRhXutlLLG8XIZjj5XGeyoUZobEtnkOn/M/S**
Where the resulting salt is not exactly the one I used for hashing, i.e. that last character of the salt value is always different.

**The randomly generated salt is: XKFB8DHMiXaYTzRAHtRhX7**

**The resulting salt value is: XKFB8DHMiXaYTzRAHtRhXu**

My question is what could be the problem, and how could I get the same randomly generated salt value embedded in the password hashed string without getting it changed?

Comment: Why not use password_hash? http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: You don't need to generate salt, `password_hash()` will do it for you.

Comment: Go with zaph 's answer that's the recommended way, but read this [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16280909/575765) if you are interested in the reasons of the truncated salt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simpler and more secure to just use [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and the companion [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) for PHP.

Use the CRYPT_BLOWFISH algorithm to create the hash. This will produce a standard crypt() compatible hash using the "$2y$" identifier.

**No salt** needs to be supplied and is best not to supply one, in PHP 7.x the salt option has been removed.

Example: `password_hash("aPassword", PASSWORD_BCRYPT)`

Comment: Im trying to use the following code to make sure the same salt is being used in hashing:
`<?php
        $binarySalt = mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
        $salt = substr(strtr(base64_encode($binarySalt), '+', '.'), 0, 22);
        $Password="test";
        echo nl2br ("Salt Value is: " . $salt . "\n");
        $cost=8; 
        $EncryptedEnteredPassword = password_hash($Password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => $cost, 'salt' => $salt]);
        echo nl2br("Encrypted Password: " . $EncryptedEnteredPassword . "\n");
        ?>` 


The last salt character is different

Comment: The point is not to use the same salt, why do you want to use the same salt?

Comment: I am not using it, I just echoed it so I could verify what is going on. I just need to know why I am getting a different salt's last character